# How to prove: if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus

How to prove this statement use the most simple way: 
if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$

Comment: This's essentially the Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: Wikipedia has 2 proofs of that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Proving_the_theorems

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Proof_of_the_boundedness_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest way :).

$[a,b]$ is compact and thus the image $f([a,b])$ is also compact, since $f$ is continuous. In particular, it is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ is unbounded. Then you can find $f(x_i)$, for $i\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $|f(x_i)|>i$. Because $[a,b]$ is compact the sequence $(x_i)_i$ has a subsequence that converges to some $x\in [a,b]$. Use the definition of continuity of $f$ in terms of limits to derive a contradiction.